# mpif90 not found but it's intsalled

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to run a makefile and came across two errors. When I run make I get this:

```
$ make
mpif90 -xHost -ip -fpp -O3 -align  -I/include/intel64/lp64 -I/include/fftw -c integ-Coul.F
make: mpif90: Command not found
make: *** [makefile:181: integ-Coul.o] Error 127
```

So, I already have installed openmpi-devel and the file mpif90 it's in the /usr/lib64/openmpi/bin folder, but the error keeps reocurring.

This is the makefile

```
#
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .f .F .for .cpp .F90 .cu .o 

#FC=ifort -xHost -ip -fpp
FC = mpif90 -xHost -ip -fpp
FREE = -free

# use this flag for debugging and coding up
SAFE = #-g -traceback -check all #-fstack-protector -assume protect_parens -implicitnone -warn all 

FFLAGS1 = -O3 -align 
FFLAGS2 = -O2 -align -qopenmp -parallel $(FREE) $(SAFE)

LDFLAGS = -static-intel

CXX = icpc -std=c++11
SAFE_CXX = #-g -traceback
CFLAGS = -O2 -align -xHost -ip -qopenmp -fno-exceptions -restrict $(SAFE_CXX)

# MKLROOT  = If MKLROOT is not defined in your environment, edit and uncomment this line
LIB_BLAS   = -lmkl_blas95_lp64
LIB_LAPACK = -lmkl_lapack95_lp64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core
LIB_OMP    = -liomp5 -lpthread
INCS_MKL   = -I$(MKLROOT)/include/intel64/lp64 -I$(MKLROOT)/include/fftw

# Uncomment the lines below when compiling for GPUs
# GPU_DEFS options:
#   -DGPU_TIMING       : Print timings (CPU/GPU)
#   -DUSE_GPU          : Compile with GPU support
#   -DGPU_DEBUG        : Print some debug messages
#   -DGPU_SYGVDM_VER   : Use multi-gpu version of SYGVD (faster than single-gpu even with 1 gpu)
#   -DGPU_SYGVD2S_VER  : Use two stage version of SYGVD (faster, but needs more memory)
#   -DGPU_DONT_PIN_MEM : Don't use pinned memory for faster transfers (in Fortran code)
#   -DGPU_PIN_MEM_WORK : Use pinned memory for work spaces (in C code)
#GPU_DEFS  = -DUSE_GPU
#
ifneq (,$(findstring USE_GPU,$(GPU_DEFS)))
# CUDA compiler
NVCC = nvcc
# compute capality (depends on your GPU, check!)
SM = 35
#SAFE_NVCC = -g -lineinfo
NVCCFLAGS = -O3 -gencode arch=compute_${SM},code=sm_${SM} -Xcompiler "-fno-strict-aliasing -march=native -fno-exceptions" $(SAFE_NVCC)
# -fno-strict-aliasing
#
# CUDA and MAGMA paths:
CUDADIR   = /usr/local/cuda
MAGMADIR  = /opt/magma
#
# CUDA and MAGMA libs:
# dynamic linking:
#LIB_CUDA  = -L$(CUDADIR)/lib64 -lcublas -lcusparse -lcudart
# static linking:
LIB_CUDA  = -L$(CUDADIR)/lib64 -lcublas_static -lcusparse_static -lculibos -lcudart_static -ldl
LIB_MAGMA = $(MAGMADIR)/lib/libmagma.a
#
LIB_GPU   = $(LIB_MAGMA) $(LIB_CUDA) -lstdc++
INCS_GPU  = -I$(CUDADIR)/include -I$(MAGMADIR)/include
endif

LIB  = $(LIB_GPU) $(LIB_BLAS) $(LIB_LAPACK) $(LIB_OMP) -lrt
INCS = $(INCS_MKL)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# general rules
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#INCS1   = comun.inc integcoul.inc m2cdat.inc $(INCS)

SOURCE1 = integ-Coul.o \
          Coul0sim.o \
          m2caux3-Coul.o \
          abcpes-Coul.o \
          ckplm-Coul.o \
          util-Coul.o

SOURCE2 = constants_m.o \
          Matrix_math.o \
          exec_time.o \
          types_EHT.o \
          types_MM.o \
          parameters.o \
                  MPI_defs.o \
          OPT_parent.o \
          parameters_MM.o \
          checklist.o \
          allocation_m.o \
          util.o \
          EHT_input.o \
          tuning.o \
                  IdentifyNonBonded.o \
          babel_routines.o \
          babel.o \
          gmx2mdflex.o \
                  namd2mdflex.o \
          structure.o \
          md_read.o \
          md_setup.o \
          f_intra.o \
          f_inter.o \
          md_output.o \
          pbc.o \
          overlap_D.o \
          STO.o \
          multip_routines.o \
          LCMO_Builder.o \
          Coulomb.o \
          DP_main.o \
          td_dp.o \
          DP_FMO.o \
          dipole_phi.o \
                  EnvField.o \
          polarizability.o \
          hamiltonians.o \
          QCModel_Huckel.o \
          diabatic-Ehren.o \
          HuckelForces.o \
          Ehrenfest.o \
          CoulInt_QMMM.o \
          FMO.o \
          electron_hole_DP.o \
          AlphaPolar.o \
          data_output.o \
                  backup_MM.o \
          Berendsen.o \
          NoseHoover.o \
          NoseHoover_Reversible.o \
                  NVE.o \
          VDOS_m.o \
          MM_dynamics.o \
          MM_driver.o \
          film_STO.o \
          DOS_m.o \
          oscillator.o \
          ga_QCModel.o \
          cost_tuning_EH.o \
          cost_tuning_MM.o \
          nonlinearCG.o \
          CG_class.o \
          MM_ERG_class.o \
          nonlinear-sidekick.o \
          FF_OPT_class.o \
          CG_EH_driver.o \
          ga_routines.o \
          CG_MM_driver.o \
          vibes_driver.o \
          solvated_M.o \
          DOS_tool.o \
          backup.o \
          auto_correlation.o \
          ElHl_schroedinger.o \
          diagnostic.o \
          qdynamics.o \
                  Taylor.o \
          ElHl_Chebyshev.o \
                  ElHl_Chebyshev_GPU.o \
          AO_adiabatic.o \
          Chebyshev_driver.o \
          eigen_driver.o \
          ga_driver.o \
          avrg_confgs.o \
          main.o

SOURCE_GPU = GPU_Interface.o \
             Taylor_gpu.o
#             Chebyshev_gpu.o

ifneq (,$(findstring USE_GPU,$(GPU_DEFS)))
SOURCE_CUDA= Chebyshev_gpu_kernels.o \
             dzgemv_kernels.o
endif


a: $(SOURCE1) $(SOURCE2) $(SOURCE_GPU) $(SOURCE_CUDA)
    rm -f a
    $(FC) $(INCS) $(LDFLAGS) -o a $(SOURCE1) $(SOURCE2) $(SOURCE_GPU) $(SOURCE_CUDA) $(LIB) 


.F.o:
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS1) $(INCS) -c $<

.f.o:
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS2) $(INCS) $(GPU_DEFS) -c $<

.F90.o:
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS1) $(INCS) $(GPU_DEFS) -c $<

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCS_GPU) $(GPU_DEFS) -c $<

.cu.o:
    $(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(INCS_GPU) $(GPU_DEFS) -c $<


clean: 
    -rm -f a *.o *.mod; touch *.f

depend:
    @echo -en "Searching module dependencies..."
    @chmod +x ./makedepend.bsh
    @./makedepend.bsh > dependencies.txt
    @echo -en " done.\n"


## Dependency list:
-include dependencies.txt
```

I don't have much experience so I would really appreciate some help with this. Thank you all.

Ps.: my SO is Fedora 32

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable contains the set of directories that the shell will use to search for programs to run.  If you want to be able to type `mpif90` at the shell prompt and have the shell find it, you'll have to add the directory `/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I added a alias for mpif90 but got the same error message.

Comment: I'd try the `PATH` variable. Commands are invoked with `/bin/sh -c` which executes a command non-interactively. From what I can tell only interactive shells read the `.bashrc` (or other rc), where I assume you have put the alias.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought creating an alias was the same as doing a PATH variable. So, I've looked up and created a PATH with this line of code "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpif90". But still got the error.

Comment: Try "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin"

Comment: Remember to tag people in the comment field, starting it with e.g. "@Andreas", since SO then sends notifications the the person you respond to. It's hard to keep track of ongoing discussions if you don't.

Comment: make doesn't run `/bin/bash`, it runs `/bin/sh` (by default).  In a non-interactive shell, aliases are not present.  You must use `PATH`.  A tip is, if you type `mpif90` at the shell prompt and it runs, then your `PATH` is set correctly and `make` will work.  If not, not.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for the tip. I've tried "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin" as well, but when I run make mpif90 is still not recognized. Altought, when I run mpif90 on the prompt as MadScientist said, the command works.

Comment: @MadScientist The system did recognize mpif90 as a command the problem is when running make.

Comment: Did you remember to remove the alias, or is that still set in your shell?  Make doesn't know anything about aliases, which are internal shell features (make != shell).  In your shell where it works to run `mpif90`, try running `type -a mpif90`.  Does it print an alias or function?  If so that's why it works.

Comment: @MadScientist No, I did remove the alias. The type -a command returns "mpif90 is /usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpif90".

Comment: If you change your `FC` variable to `FC = echo $$PATH; mpif90 -xHost -ip -fpp` does it show the right path?

Comment: Please update the question with info like this: it's not readable to add formatted content like that into comments.  You say "no" when I asked if it showed the right path, but I see the right directory on the path so...?  You didn't mention what version of GNU make you are using.  If you are using GNU make 4.3 there is an issue with the version of gnulib in that version of GNU make, where it gets confused between directories and executables on the PATH.  If you look in each of the directories on your PATH do any of them have a _subdirectory_ named `mpif90` in them?

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you so much for all the help, I managed to install it using ifort. Still don't know why gfortran wasn't able to compile the files tough.